# Запретить браузеру запоминать значения поля формы

Tags: html, jquery, form

Есть форма с полем "Город", для поля сделан JQuery автокомплит, после каждого действия пользователя введённый текст через ajax отпрвляется скрипту php который в свою очередь отдаёт массив со списком найденных по введённому тексту городов. Найденные города отображаются в специальном красивом контейнере ниже поля ввода, где их может выбрать пользователь http://joxi.ru/eAOqKQWHolqYmo .

Недавно сзаметили что браузер начал запоминать ранее вводимые значения и выводить подсказку параллельно с нашим контейнером найденных налету городов http://joxi.ru/52a1M7Btaq3420 . Попытка запретить запоминание с помощью атрибута autocomplite="off" для поля формы, к успеху не привела. К тому же на поле стала ругаться Jquery валидация.

Вот собственно и вопрос, как запретить браузеру запоминать вводимые в текстовые поля формы значения? Или хотябы не показывать их как подсказку?

Comment: Опечатка? Правильно `autocomplete`.

Comment: В принципе, вы не можете _запретить_ юзер-агенту показывать удобные для пользователя вещи, вы можете лишь _попросить_ его об этом. </зануда mode off>

Comment: т.е. не получится, я правильно понял? (да в autocomplete возможно опечатался).

Comment: Ну, большинство браузеров по идее слушаются autocomplete=off. Но гарантию вам никто дать не может, браузер имеет право отступать от стандарта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такая тема поднималась на оригинальном SO и помечена как решенная.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/582292/272885

Современные браузеры поддерживают атрибут autocomplete **в форме**, а не в инпуте. IE когда-то работал с одноименным атрибутом инпута, но перешел к стандартному поведению с v11.

Answer (score 0):

Тема старая, но вдруг кому пригодится решение:

```
<input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password"  readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly')">
```

Comment: В FireFox выявилось что этот хак обходится нажатием tab-а, для решения этого добавить autocomplete="off" в тэг form